# Facing result of string concatination too long

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

While inserting data into table i was facing error string literal too long.
Hence to fix this issue i used concatenation operater.
For eg : values is ' || ' too big
But still the issue is not solved , now facing result of string concatenation is too long.
The data type of column is clob.

```
Create table testlongstring(name clob)
Insert into testlongstring values('value is too '|| ' big')
```

Facing issue result of string concatenation is too long.

If i put normal string 'value is too big'
It gives strinf litteral too long

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are concatenating two `CHAR`/`VARCHAR2` literal values and the output is a `CHAR`/`VARCHAR2` literal which will fail if the length of the two expressions you are concatenating is more than 4000 bytes.

For example:

```sql
Insert into testlongstring values(
  RPAD('a', 4000, 'a') || RPAD('b', 4000, 'b')
);
```

Will try to create a 8000 byte string (before inserting into the table) and will fail with the error:

> ```
> ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
> ```

What you need to do is concatenate a `CLOB` value first, such as `EMPTY_CLOB()`, and then the concatenation operator will return a `CLOB` value:

```sql
Insert into testlongstring values(
  EMPTY_CLOB() || RPAD('a', 4000, 'a') || RPAD('b', 4000, 'b')
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ace855f85cb93ca6494db93531b037be)*